# Simpify Excel Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this Excel Code, which selects a value, and tries to find out if its empty and print a message if its empty otherwise the value.
However I find it too repeditive for this simple task.
Is there a cleaner solution?

```
=IF(
    ISBLANK(
        INDEX(TWerte[#Daten];
            MATCH(Serialnummer;TWerte[Serialnummer];0);
            MATCH($B20;TWerte[#Kopfzeilen];0)
        )
    );
    "no Value";
    INDEX(TWerte[#Daten];
        MATCH(Serialnummer;TWerte[Serialnummer];0);
        MATCH($B20;TWerte[#Kopfzeilen];0)
    )
)
```

Comment: I don't think you have many options. You could use a formula-based name. Then again, i was thinking about a formula that involves `IFERROR`, but i can't quite figure out a way to implement it. Any information about the value to be analysed? Will it be a number? A text? Can be both?

Comment: I don't think there is a cleaner solution, but if you post a data example input and expected output, maybe somebody can help you out

Comment: Post your sample data and then output by your formula. Also mention version of excel you are using. Excel365 have some dynamic formula which may solve your problem very easily.

Comment: If you have Excel 365 you can use [`LET`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) to avoid duplicating parts of your formula

Comment: @chrisneilsen: `LET` would be my favourite solution, however my Office 365 does not include it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if below suggestion is helpful for you or not. Use only the `INDEX` portion of the formula like below.

`INDEX(TWerte[#Daten]; MATCH(Serialnummer;TWerte[Serialnummer];0); MATCH($B20;TWerte[#Kopfzeilen];0)`

And for these formula cells, apply custom cell formatting as shown below.

`0;-0;"No Value"`

[image]

Comment: Sorry. Not a solution. The cell contains a 0 but prints nothing. So far that is ok. But in another cell I test the contents and it must not test against 0 if the cell acutally contains nothing. Therefore it is easier to test against an error message.